# what is difference between [::2] and [:,:,2]

Tags: python

returns are different.

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('/home/berkay/PycharmProjects/opencv/advanced lane line/lena.jpg')
hls_s = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HLS)[:,:,2]
print(hls_s)
```

and

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('/home/berkay/PycharmProjects/opencv/advanced lane line/lena.jpg')
hls_s = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HLS)[::2]
print(hls_s)
```

what is difference between [::2] and [:,:,2]
and for what purpose are they used?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the docs of numpy indexing. [ask]

Answer (score 2):

The argmument in the `[]` is passed to the `__getitem__` method on the object, with `:` or `::` being parsed as a slice object. When you index with `:,:,2` you are creating a tuple containing two slices and an `int`.

For your example `obj[::2]` calls `obj.__getitem__(Slice(None, None, 2))` whereas `obj[:,:,2]` calls `obj.__getitem__((Slice(None, None, None), Slice(None, None, None), 2)]`

For numpy arrays, I think the multiple slices are used for slicing different dimensions.